# Screen goes black every few seconds on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, screen, brightness

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my notebook and I have the following problem: My screen goes black every few seconds and when I hit a key on the keyboard in comes back. It is really annoying as I basically cant use my laptop.

When I go to **Settings>Power** The **Blank Screen** settings is off and the **Dim screen when inactive** is also off.

When I type in the console: `gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power idle-dim` the returned value is **false**

Can someone help me understand how I could fix this? I really appreciate any help you can provide as I am really desperate

Comment: This just started happening to me on a 9 month old 18.04 installation.  I "solved" it using Windows techniques, ie, a reboot.  But I am curious what's going on, I have never seen this before.

Comment: Same problem here. Rebooting seems to fix it, but the problem comes back after a while